# RouterModule.forRoot() called twice in a Module Federation architecture

Tags: angular, webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: RouterModule.forRoot() called twice. Lazy loaded modules should use RouterModule.forChild() instead.`

> Question: I am using "webpack": "5.67.0" and "@angular-architects/module-federation": "^14.1.1", and I have both the host app and remote app working in isolation. But when I try the view the remote app inside of the shell it is giving me that error from above. When I do add the forChild() to the remote my styles and images don't come from the remote they come from the host only. What am I doing wrong?

Webpack config from host:

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "container",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },   
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        library: { type: "module" },

        // For remotes (please adjust)
        // name: "container",
        // filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        // exposes: {
        //     './Component': './/src/app/app.component.ts',
        // },        
        
        // For hosts (please adjust)
        remotes: {
          "web": "http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js",
        },

        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: '>= 13.2.4' }, 
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: '>= 13.2.4' }, 
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: '>= 13.2.4' }, 
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: '>= 13.2.4' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })
        
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

Webpack config from remote:

```
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");

const share = mf.share
const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  ['home']);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "web",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },   
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'svg-url-loader',
                options: {
                  limit: 10000,
                },
              },
            ],
        },
        {
            test: /\.jpe?g$|\.ico$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$|\.wav$|\.mp3$|\.css/,
            use: {
                loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
            }
        }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        library: { type: "module" },
        name: "web",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
          './WebsiteModule': './src/app/app.module.ts',
        },
        shared: 
        share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: '>= 13.2.4', }, 
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: '>= 13.2.4', }, 
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: '>= 13.2.4', }, 
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, eager: true, requiredVersion: '>= 13.2.4', },
          "@angular/material": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, eager: true },
          "@angular/cdk": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, eager: true },
          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })
        
    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

Comment: The question is a bit what you expect here? You can’t really have routing in remotes as the host will do the routing as soon as you federate it in?

Comment: @MikeOne Ok, I get it. So I would need to move my routing to the host, and remove them from the remotes? But that would break the remote app if the app was running on its own, wouldn't it?

Comment: Host and remote(s) are basically becoming one application so solving routing can be complex.

Comment: To expand on that a bit more, it’s called Mfe’s for a reason, i.e. Micro frontends. The use case is fine for small mini apps (usually without routing and pretty simple) as remotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can change o public path of auto for the url that is serving the microfrontend, example

```
publicPath: "auto"
```

to

```
publicPath: "localhost:5000"
```